# php if url contain `google.com` not do something

Tags: php

there have many urls in a foreach:

```
http://encrypted.google.com
http://www.bing.com
http://login.yahoo.com
```

how to make if url contain `google.com` jump, else echo.

something put should be

```
http://www.bing.com
http://login.yahoo.com
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($urls as $u) {
     if(stripos($u,'google.com')) continue;
     echo $u;
}
```

Comment: -1 This is not going to work for URLs starting with `google.com`. Read the documentation carefully. I can see a lot of people didn't either.

Comment: Note that stripos can return values which evaluate as false, while not being actually false, so you'd want what the other answer has, which uses !== false. One of the joys of dynamic typing.

Comment: I realize that but in this case, all urls start with http://. If that was not the case then you would want to use the !== false check.

Comment: you shouldn't risk the robustness of code just for the sake of not typing `!== false`

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
<?php
     if(strpos($link, 'google.com') === false){
        // does not have google.com
     }else{
        // does have google.com
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($yourUrls as $url){
  if(strpos($url, 'google.com')){
    continue;
  }else{
    echo $url;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems a little overkill. If you have an `if...else`, you don't need `continue`, and vice versa.

Comment: True, but it is clearer like this, for instance if you want to add extra code later on. There is no real reason not to do this, as it's not going to make any measurable difference